# In SSIS 2012, what is the purpose of flagging a package as an "Entry Point" package

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssis

In the Visual Studio designer you can right click on a SSIS package and designate it as an "Entry Point" package"

[image: Screen shot of Visual Studio designer]

Doing a search I found [this page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878097.aspx) which states:

> The value of 1 signifies that the package is meant to be started
>   directly. The value of 0 signifies that the package is meant to be
>   started by another package with the Execute Package task. The default
>   value is 1.

With this flag enabled and disabled I have been able to execute a package directly.

What is the purpose of enabling or disabling this flag?  Is it merely to document the intentions of your own SSIS packages or does SQL Server/SSIS behave differently when it enabled or disabled?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's one behaviour I can think of:

Only packages with "Entry Point Package" set to 1 can be executed by catalog.create_execution

(see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878034.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

On a side note:

The default scope on the parameters configuration page in the Integration Services Catalogs is called "**Entry-point packages and project**".

You will probably want to disable this flag on child packages so that their parameters doesn't show up and clutter the configuration dialog.